# Usar if dentro de foreach

Tags: php, loop, if, foreach

Estou tentando alterar a ordem com que os resultados aparecem dentro de um loop usando foreach. O que eu preciso é que os números maiores que cinco apareçam primeiro, seguidos do restante dos números. Então tentei algo assim:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($numeros as $numero){
    if($numero > 5){
        echo '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Mas não está funcionando.

Comment: Você está imprimindo a mesma coisa independente de se é maior q 5 ou não

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Respondi apenas para ilustrar o que está havendo. O que acontece no seu código, é que você criou uma condição que pode ser lida assim:

1. Itere em todos os elementos
2. Se for maior que cinco, imprima.
3. senão, imprima.

Aí todos aparecem. Experimente este código, com o mesmo problema, mas com uma "dica" dentro do `if` para entender o que houve:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($numeros as $numero){
    if($numero > 5){
        echo '<li>MAIOR QUE CINCO - '.$numero.'</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li>MENOR OU IGUAL - '.$numero.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Uma solução simplista seria separar os loops (ainda didaticamente, pois no caso prático, teriamos provavelmente soluções bem melhores):

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($numeros as $numero){
    if($numero > 5){
        echo '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
    }
}
foreach($numeros as $numero){
    if($numero <= 5) {
        echo '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Ficamos assim:

1. Itere em todos os elementos
2. Se for maior que cinco, imprima.
3. Itere em todos os elementos NOVAMENTE
4. Apenas se for menor ou igual a cinco, imprima.

> Esta é uma resposta didática. No caso prático, poderiam ser feitas várias otimizações, dependendo do uso dos dados.

Comment: Ia postar isso agora, mas como já tá aí que fique o seu, ^^

Comment: @Bacco Eu achei que, caso a primeira condição não fosse satisfeita, ele pularia para a segunda.

Comment: Isso foi um erro de lógica , porque como um `foreach` percorre todos os itens de um *array*, a cada item percorrido ele vai verificar se é maior q 5 e imprimir, se não for maior q 5 ele imprime do mesmo jeito. Era isso q seu código estava fazendo. Por isso foi necessário fazer 2 `foreach`, para que cada um faça uma verificação diferente.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com um segundo código, que ilustra o que houve. Seu `if` funciona, mas a lógica não é adequada para o resultado pretendido.

Comment: Acho que uma solução com ordenação ficaria melhor, não?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Acontece :) ... Mas é pior quando a gente posta e alguem 5 segundos antes postou a mesma coisa e a gente não viu a tempo.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar depende muito de o q ele quer fazer, não sei exatamente o que ele quer, seria interessante o marcelo2605 explicasse exatamente o que quer, assim poderíamos otimizar sua solução.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode também tratar os `arrays` antes de imprimir, da seguinte maneira:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
asort($numeros); // necessário se o array estiver desordenado
$num = 5; // valor limite
$pos = array_search($num,$numeros); // pega a posição do array conforme valor determinado
$numerosMenores = array_slice($numeros,0,$pos); // pega parte do array com os numeros menores
$numerosMaiores = array_slice($numeros,$pos); // pega parte do array com os numeros maiores
$numeros = array_merge($numerosMaiores, $numerosMenores); //funde os arrays

foreach($numeros as $numero){
    echo '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**OBS:** Se seu array estiver fora de ordem você precisará primeiramente ordená-lo, `asort($numero)`, ou isto não funcionará.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de com PHP você poder fazer muitas coisas de muitas formas diferentes isso não significa que você vai martelar um parafuso só porque não encontrou a chave certa.

Com isso em mente, analise o que você quer fazer: "Uma condição dentro de uma iteração". O que essa condição vai fazer? "Ela vai filtrar um determinado resultado antes de executar a rotina sobre ele".

Sendo assim, use a ferramenta certa ou mais apropriada para a tarefa em questão: [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/array_filter)

Essa função vai receber um dado array de entrada e filtrá-lo de acordo com a função passada como segundo argumento. Essa função pode ser uma string para alguma função conhecida pelo programa (como uma função nativa, por exemplo), uma função anônima ou até mesmo um método de objeto.

```
$data = array( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );

$data = array_filter(

    $data,

    function( $current ) {

        return ( $current <= 5 );
    }
);
```

**$data**, agora tem apenas cinco elementos, de um a cinco.

*"Mas eu tenho que imprimir tudo"*

Aqui é que entram as diversas possibilidades. Uma bacana seria computar a diferença do array de entrada para esse filtrado, com [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/array_diff)

*"Mas ainda assim eu vou ter que iterar pra imprimir"*

Só se você quiser. Pois uma matriz unidimensional pode perfeitamente ser impressa com `implode()`, com HTML e tudo:

```
$data = array( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );

$lowerThanFive = array_filter(

    $data,

    function( $current ) {

        return ( $current <= 5 );
    }
);

printf(

    "<ul>\n    <li>%s</li>\n</ul>",

    implode( "</li>\n    <li>", $lowerThanFive )
);

printf(

    "\n\n<ul>\n    <li>%s</li>\n</ul>",

    implode( "</li>\n    <li>", array_diff( $data, $lowerThanFive ) )
);
```

Note que, por se tratar de um exemplo, eu criei duas listas não-ordenadas distintas, principalmente para demonstrar que funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de exibir dentro do foreach, armazene esses valores dentro de uma string e quando terminar o look imprima os $maiores e depois os $menores

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$maiores='';
$menores='';
echo '<ul>';
foreach($numeros as $numero){
if($numero > 5){
    $maiores.= '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
}else{
    $menores.= '<li>'.$numero.'</li>';
  }
}
echo $maiores;
echo $menores;
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira mais simples ainda para resolver isso, levando em conta que o importante é selecionar do maior para o menor e ganhar performance:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
rsort($numeros);

foreach($numeros as $numeroSelecionado)
{
    echo $numeroSelecionado.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Quem negativou, poderia explicar o motivo?

Comment: Talvez quem tem feito isso não entendeu seu ponto de vista que, apesar de correto, no cenário real que não o original apresentado pode não funcionar como pretendido pois tudo indica que o array em questão não pode ter sua estrutura ordenada e sim apenas apresentada de forma diferente.

Comment: Concordo, mas como todos os exemplos são baseados no array original proposto, isso se torna um paradoxo de quem negativou. Negativar de forma irresponsável vai contra as regras, e no caso de dúvida sobre o método que usei bastava que ele apenas comentasse e a tirasse para chegar a uma conclusão justa. Mas, vida que segue rsrs

Comment: Pois é, mas seja lá que foi preferiu gastar a própria reputação para negativar sem pensar antes. Vai entender...